# Analyzing the behavior of a threaded program

Tags: linux, multithreading

Is there an application that will do what [Threadscope](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/threadscope/) or the parallel tools of Visual Studio does for multithreaded program analysis in Linux?

Comment: For those people who know neither Threadscope nor Visual Studio but know about Linux debugging tools, what features are you after?

Comment: @Gilles: Thanks. I'm after, for example, how much work each thread has done, how much waiting time per thread, etc. As much info about how a multithreaded program has run as possible.

Answer (score 3):

There are many tools. `Intel VTune Amplifier` (formerly VTune Performance Analyzer), Oracle Solaris Studio for RedHat Linux includes visual `Thread Analyzer`. And a number of tools were mentioned in this [Stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375913/what-can-i-use-to-profile-c-code-in-linux/378024#378024) or [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/638090/profiling-c-multi-threaded-applications).

Many of the available profiling tools can be accessed via [Eclipse Linux Tools](http://www.eclipse.org/linuxtools/) project.